# custom attribute on custom Button does not show

Tags: android, button, custom-controls

I extended the Button widget to be able to apply several custom attributes.
One of the attributes is a color filter I try to apply to its background when the button is created. It does not work. (See the screen shots and code below)
I tried to directly set the background color, on the same code place, and it does change the background color, but it is not what I need, since I am using my own button PNGs.

there are 2 problems so far:

1. The color filter is not applied
2. The custom button is offset, clipped and it is not clickable

The second button uses the normal button, and it is positioned as expected and it is clickable. The second screenshot shows that the correct color is indeed chosen, and that it is possible to change the button background color at that point in the code.

Code:

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    private int backGroundColor;

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, 
            R.styleable.MyButton, 
            defStyle, 
            0);

        try {
            Resources res = getResources();
            switch( a.getInteger(R.styleable.MyButton_type, 0) ) {
            case 0: 
                backGroundColor = res.getColor(R.color.Black); break;
            case 1: 
                backGroundColor = res.getColor(R.color.Red); break;
            case 2: 
                backGroundColor = res.getColor(R.color.DimGray); break;
            }
            getBackground().setColorFilter(backGroundColor, Mode.MULTIPLY);
            //setBackgroundColor(backGroundColor)
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public MyButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }
}
```

The XML I used:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.example.test.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="BTN1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/key_selector"
        app:type="RedButton"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/key_selector"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:text="BTN2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot of setColorFilter() outcome
[image]

Screenshot of setBackgroundColor() outcome
[image]

**EDIT** 
This is the selector XML I use for the normal and pressed states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/key1_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/key1"/>


</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The custom button is offset, clipped and it is not clickable

That's due to your use of the constructors. The `Button` class does chain between its constructors but it doesn't pass `0` to the last constructor as the style(from the second constructor which is the one used), it passes an internal style(what makes a visual `Button` in the end). If you were to pass:

```
this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.buttonStyle);
```

the `Button` should be ok.

> The color filter is not applied

The code for setting the color filter should work with no problems after you make the correction above. When you'll set the filter you'll see that both buttons will have the filter applied to them(as they have the same bitmap(I'm assuming you use an image)). This is happening because the drawables of the same type share a constant state. You can read more from Romain Guy's explanation [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/):

```
getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(backGroundColor, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Let me know if this solves the problem(from what I understood):

```
public static class MyButton extends Button {

    private int backGroundColor;
    private StateListDrawable mSld;
    private PorterDuffColorFilter mColorFilter;
    private boolean mHandled = false;

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // ...
        try {
            //...
            mSld = (StateListDrawable) getBackground();
            mColorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(backGroundColor,
                    Mode.MULTIPLY);
            mSld.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!mHandled) {
            final Drawable current = mSld.getCurrent();
            current.mutate();
            current.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
            mHandled = true;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Comment: The fix to the contructors style solved the offset, the clipping and the clickable problems.

Comment: The color problem is not 100% solved. I tried with and without mutate(). Without mutate() all buttons have initially the same color, but they get their own color when you click on them. With mutate() (+ invalidate() + requestLayout() as indicated in the guides) all buttons get their color right away ... but the first. The first button in the row does not get any color until it is clicked. Any idea why?

Comment: @ilomambo Maybe you can share some code about how you handle the "clicks"?

Comment: At this point the only handling is by using a key selector. I haven't coded, nor defined yet the `onClick` method. I will add the selector code to the body of the question. The pressed state is just a displacement of the normal state.

Comment: Maybe this can shed some light on what's happening. My current bypass is to insert a normal button as the first one, with 0dp width and height and made invisible + a twist, I define also the same key selector. It works. If I don't define the key selector then it does not work, and the second button does not get its color until clicked.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. It does not seem "natural" though.  If you understand what was going on, a few clarifying words would be welcome.

Comment: @ilomambo Well a `DrawableContainer`(as `StateListDrawable` is) implementation of the `setColorFilter()` method sets the color filter only on the current state drawable. The problem is that using `mSld.getCurrent()` doesn't work at the constructor level(I don't know why, probably because the `Button` isn't in an actual state there) so I delayed setting the color filter on the current drawable until the very last moment(when it's about to be drawn on the screen).

Comment: Maybe you are interested to know I found a more elegant solution. The method to set the color filter is `onSizeChanged()`. No need to set the filter for the current drawable, just `getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(backgroundColor, Mode.MULTIPLY)`

Comment: @ilomambo The same thing  could be done in `onDraw()`, `onMeasure` and other lifecycle callbacks. The idea was you can't do it at the constructor level.

Comment: Right, but I logged all the calls and `onDraw()` and `onMeasure()` are called multiple times for the same button, hence requiring the `boolean mHandled` flag. On the other hand `onSizeChanged()` is called only once (at least it is like this in my intended app)